# Is there a default explicit conversion function for user-defined class (c++)?

Tags: c++, class, casting, explicit

Can I convert compatible non-pointer objects without actually defining a cast operator? So if B inherits from A:

```
A a;
B b;
```

Will `(A)b` compile if I donot provide my own cast operator?

Edit: It does seem to compile. Is it because there is a default conversion cast operator or the compiler recognizes the compatibility and uses the default copying constructor or assignment operator in assignments for example?

Comment: Did you, I don't know, like, **try it**?

Comment: Works with my compiler. But I don't understand how and why it works, as seen in my edit part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does compile (http://ideone.com/CXbeh0)

By default `A` is copyable. The copy constructor has signature `A::A(A const &)`. Since instance of `B` is implicitly convertible to `A const &`, the cast will be resolved using `A`'s copy constructor.

The conversion to reference applies to the (also implicitly generated) copy assignment operator too, so `a = b` again compiles using `A &A::operator=(A const &)`.

Keep in mind, that the new object is of type A, not B, so it does not contain any additional information the original instance of B did. That is rarely what you want.

On a side-note, it is recommended in C++ to forget that C-style cast exists and use the more specific cast types of C++:

- The function-style cast for explicit request to create a temporary of target type using matching constructor; also allows using multi-parameter constructors.
- The `static_cast`, for compatible types only.
- The `dynamic_cast` for upcasting pointers/references with run-time
  check.
- `const_cast` to only handle const.
- And `reinterpret_cast` if you really need to play pointer tricks, but beware of aliasing rules.

Answer (score 0):

By no user-defined constructors or operators are defined, then:

```
(A)b
```

will be implemented as if:

```
A(b) //Calls A copy-constructor: A::A(const A&)
```

That is, it will create a temporary of A copy-constructing from the argument.

This is called *object splicing* and it is usually a bad idea, because you are copying some fields of B, but not others. YMMV.